# Powershell param replaces last input

Tags: powershell

I have the below code written which when I use the cmd

`./generate.ps1 -name  'Test' -class 'first' -subject 'Maths'` generates a file with the name Control.ps1 with the following output

```
$name = "Test"
$class = "first"
$subject = "Maths"
```

But when I change my cmd to

`./generate.ps1 -name  'Test' -class 'first' -subject 'Maths', 'English'`

The last value replaces N-1 value. I tried using a foreach loop and it still replaced the N-1 value

My expected output is as below

```
$name = "Test"
$class = "first"
$subject = "Maths"
$subject = "English"
```

Also please let me know if this code can be optimized to better standards

```
param(
$name,
$class,
$subject)

MyFunction
$Script:name = $name
$Script:class = $class
$Script:subject = $subject

$ControlFile = "D:\Users\Downloads\Control.ps1"
function WriteParameterFile    
{
    New-Item -Path $ControlFile -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null                

    Add-Content -Path $ControlFile -Value ('${0} = "{1}"' -f @("name",$name))
    Add-Content -Path $ControlFile -Value ('${0} = "{1}"' -f @("class",$class))
    Add-Content -Path $ControlFile -Value ('${0} = "{1}"' -f @("subject",$subject))

}

WriteParameterFile $ControlFile
```

Comment: What is `MyFunction` ? What is the expected output to the file when `$subject` has more than one value?

Comment: Use `-Value ('${0} = "{1}"' -f  "name",$script:name)` in your `WriteParameterFile` function. Do the same for 'class' and 'subject' and remove `MyFunction` (unless that is another function you didn't show..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can make your code more dynamic using [`$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psboundparameters). This would be able to handle the addition of more parameters to your `param` block as well as changing the parameter types from `[string]` to `[string[]]`:

```
param(
    [string] $Name,
    [string] $Class,
    [string[]] $Subject
)

$PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Value -is [string[]]) {
        foreach($val in $_.Value) {
            '${0} = "{1}"' -f $_.Key, $val
        }
        return
    }
    '${0} = "{1}"' -f $_.Key, $_.Value
} | Set-Content "D:\Users\Downloads\Control.ps1"
```